# Combine equal and smaller conditions on field of type text in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

I'm using Cassandra for storing data and I want to use EQUAL and NOT EQUALS query on it. The EQUAL (=) operator works fine. For the NOT EQUALS operator, I combine the result of < and > operator on the field (I created custom secondary index on every field using SASI Index). I use SASI Index to support
However, when I combine both operators = and < in a query, Cassandra reject it (the result has no row). You can see the example queries below, it is easier to understand.
This is a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id uuid,
    a int,
    b int,
    c varchar,
    d varchar,
    timestamp bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The below queries return nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 AND c < '2' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

The below queries return correct result:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a > 1 AND c = '2' ALLOW FILTERING;
SELECT * FROM test WHERE c > '2' AND d < '2' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Also, I want to ORDER BY timestamp.
Can anyone explain why Cassandra behaves like that? And how can I design the database to support any combinations?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Cassandra is different from relational databases, and requires specific data modeling around queries that you'll execute.  In your case, you're using `ALLOW FILTERING` and this lead to performing the full scan of all data. Please look to http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/ddl/ddlCQLDataModelingTOC.html, for example,and http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archTOC.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've said it before, and I'll say it again:

[image: ALLOW FILTERING is bad, bad, bad!]

And the same goes for secondary indexes.

Any time that you are not filtering your `WHERE` clause by the PRIMARY KEY, you are running what is known as a "multi-key query."  This is a known anti-pattern, because it cannot restrict itself to a partition, hence the query will need to reference multiple nodes to complete.  That is an approach that **will not scale**, and is therefore a bad idea to do with a *distributed* database.

In Cassandra you need to take a query-based modeling approach.  From what I can see, you have `id` defined as the lone PRIMARY KEY, but you're not querying by it.  Your PRIMARY KEY definition should really reflect the types of queries that you want your table to serve.

If that is a query you want to run, then your table definition will need to reflect that:

```
CREATE TABLE test_by_a_and_c (
    id uuid,
    a int,
    b int,
    c varchar,
    d varchar,
    timestamp bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (a,c,timestamp,id));
```

This will partition your data by `a`, and cluster it by `c`, `timestamp`, and `id`.  Using `c` as your first clustering key will allow your query to work.  Using `timestamp` as the second clustering key will allow your results to be sorted by timestamp.  `id` is added on the end to ensure uniqueness, which may or may not be necessary.  This definition will allow this query to work:

```
SELECT * FROM test_by_a_and_c WHERE a = 1 AND c < '2';
```

For the second query, you will need to create a *new* table which contains the same data, and adjust your PRIMARY KEY definition accordingly:

```
    CREATE TABLE test_by_c_and_a (
    id uuid,
    a int,
    b int,
    c varchar,
    d varchar,
    timestamp bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (c,a,timestamp,id));
```

This definitiuon will partition your data by `c`, and then it uses `a` as the first clustering key to satisfy your required query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_by_c_and_a WHERE c = '2' AND a > 1;
```

Cassandra guarantees that a partition is stored on a single node.  So by limiting your model with a good partition key, you are essentially ensuring that your query only has to go to one node to be solved, and that drastically reduces the amount of network time required.

> Also, I want to ORDER BY timestamp. Can anyone explain why Cassandra
>   behaves like that?

Cassandra can only enforce a sort order within a partition key.  Clustering order is essentially how the data is written to disk.  When you do not specify a partition key in the `WHERE` clause, or when a query potentially covers multiple keys, the data is returned as it is read.  First, it'll be sorted by the hashed token value of the partition key.  Then, it will be by clustering key, relative to the current partition key.

For instance, let me take your first query table and `INSERT` some random data.  If I query without a `WHERE` clause, you can see how the hashed token value of the partition key comes into play:

cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT token(a),a,b,c,d,timestamp FROM test_by_a_and_c ;

```
 system.token(a)      | a | b | c | d | timestamp
----------------------+---+---+---+---+---------------------
 -4069959284402364209 | 1 | 2 | 7 | 2 | 2017-12-14 16:33:55
 -4069959284402364209 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 1 | 2017-12-14 16:33:55
 -3248873570005575792 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2017-12-14 16:33:55
 -3248873570005575792 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 1 | 2017-12-14 16:33:55
 -2729420104000364805 | 4 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 2017-12-14 16:33:56
 -2729420104000364805 | 4 | 2 | 7 | 2 | 2017-12-14 16:33:57
  9010454139840013625 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 2017-12-14 16:33:56
  9010454139840013625 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 2017-12-14 16:33:56

(8 rows)
```

Note that values for the partition key `a` are returned in 1,2,4,3 order because of their tokens.  Plus, the `timestamp` is really only relevant for sorting within each `a`.

> And how can I design the database to support any combinations?

You cannot.  For Cassandra, your queries *must* be known ahead of time. 
 Then your tables must be designed to serve those queries.  If you require a more-dynamic query model, then you'll need to use a data store that is better suited for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I understand the limitation of Cassandra for a dynamic query model but now I'm pleased as someone answer it for me.